# move_uploaded_files not going to subdirectory with variable as name

Tags: php

Please help, I have checked everywhere to find an answer and some are close but never exactly what I need. I'm trying to have users upload files and have them placed in a directory named their `id#`. `$spid = users id` and works fine elsewhere on this page. Let's say `$spid = 100`, I would like the image to upload to `uploads/100/some.jpg`. However no matter what I do they end up in `uploads/` Here is my code: What in the world am I doing wrong?

**uploadform.html** -

```
<form action="uploads2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><p>
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

**uploads2.php**

```
$targetdir= "uploads/$spid";

if(!is_dir($targetdir)){

mkdir("uploads/".$spid, 0777);
}

$targetfile = $targetdir."/".basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$allexts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($ext, $allexts)){
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetfile)) {
print_r ($targetfile);
    echo "File upload was successful.";
} else {
    echo "An error has occured. Please try again.";
}
} else {
echo "Invalid file type. Please try again.";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because if you upload `some.jpg` the `$targetfile` would be `uploads/100some.jpg` and not `uploads/100/some.jpg`.

Change

```
$targetfile = $targetdir.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
```

to

```
$targetfile = $targetdir.'/'.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your changes and it makes the directory however still saves the file under uploads/   I also noticed that eventhough I have mkdir("uploads/".$spid, 0777); it makes the directory 0755. Could that be an issue?

Comment: can you print the `$targetfile` after the file is moved? What does it contain?

Comment: I added print_r($targetfile); right after the if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetfile)) { line. And this is the only thing I get on the screen. File is an image - image/png.The file tekaroo_logo_small.png has been uploaded.

Comment: There's no such thing in the code that you've posted. Show us more code.

Comment: sorry, very new to StackOverflow. Code has been updated.

Comment: OMG, I think I have it. And you were the key, hang on let me test.

Comment: Not yet, check updated code. Now getting invalid file type Please try again

Comment: You need to change the `umask` in order to create a publicly accessible dir, which is why `mkdir` won't do it, even when specifying `0777` See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php#1207